# c# entity , deleting a db record from a drop down list selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

How do I delete a record from drop down list selected value?

I have populated the drop down `list` from database and I am having problems to delete it with a delete button. Am I doing the right way? ( Sorry if my codes are messy )

This is how I populate my drop down list:

```
protected void dropTask()
    {
        dropListTask.DataSource = daoTask.GetAll();
        dropListTask.DataTextField = "TaskName";
        dropListTask.DataValueField = "TaskID";

        dropListTask.DataBind();
    }
```

This is the delete button :

```
  protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        { 
            Model.task del= new Model.task();
            del.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(dropListTask.SelectedValue);
            daoTask.Delete(del);
            daoTask.Save();
        }
  }
```

I need to add the postback to the btn codes, if I removed it it gives me a error that says;

`The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.`

So I put in the postback and the error is gone. Don't know if it is a right way. Please advise me how to to do it correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` means that the piece of code will only run on the first run of the page (so NOT when you click the button). 
The button click will go back to your ASP page as a post back so eventually you should invert the `if`, but in the `btnDelete_Click` method you already know is a postback so you can skip the if altogether.

I believe the error went away because, indeed, you are not executing the code in the `if` block, so nothing is deleted.

I don't know what `daoTask` is or how you do persistance in your code but that way of deleting an object from a DB does not sound right... you are creating a new one and assigning it a different ID but the flow should be different:

First find the existing object based on the id, then delete it:

```
// Don't know if 'Find' is the method you need, you should check based on what
// libraries you are using for saving/loading from DB
Model.task del = daoTask.Find(Convert.ToInt32(dropListTask.SelectedValue));
daoTask.Delete(del);
daoTask.Save();
```

Googling the error you got should have pointed you in the right direction about the fact that the problem is the DB code, rather than the ASP postback: [The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263660/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager)

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment you should do something like this:

```
Model.task del = daoTask.GetTask(dropListTask.SelectedItem.Text);
daoTask.Delete(del);
daoTask.Save();
```

By the way, I would add a `GetTask(int id)` method to your `daoTask` class to be able to find tasks by id rather than name.

Comment: Ok, then you should use your `R` part of CRUD to retrieve the task to delete... If you are using Entity Framework it could look something like `.FirstOrDefault(...)`.

Comment: i had tried to use   return context.tasks.FirstOrDefault(a => a.TaskName.Equals(name)); in the class file under method GetTask .
So   del.TaskName = daoTask.GetTask(dropListTask.SelectedItem.Text).ToString();  . tried to delete by daoTask.Delete(del); .. still can't work , pls enlighten me and be patience with a newbie like me  ... thx

Comment: You are still creating a new one and assigning it a name... you need to use the one you retrieve from `daoTask`. I have added to the answer based on your comment, see if it works :)

Comment: and this is how my delete code looks like in the class file :

 public void Delete(task del)
         {
             context.tasks.DeleteObject(del);

         }

Comment: thanks for the solution , it works! alright i'll change to the ID , thanks for the advise !

Answer (score 0):

It delete the task and fine. But you need to rebind the data to the control dropListTask to take effect the changes in UI.

Comment: btw i check mySQL database everytime i try to delete , the records seems to be there and not deleted.

Comment: If the record is not getting deleted from database, I suspect the code to delete daoTask. Check for any exceptions or use data base profiler to ensure that the query is reaching the database. To update the UI you may refer to http://forums.asp.net/t/1795945.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can call **protected void dropTask()** for rebind dropdown value after delete
```